# Original estimate and subsequent workitems

Tags: tfs

Let say i have a CMMI bug in TFS2010 and I give it an original estimate of 40. I create 2 linked (child) work items of type Task and give it each an original estimate of 10 and 30.

Is this the right way to do ? Or should I only enter the original estimate on the leaf work items (thus: only on the tasks in this case) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend you only track hour estimates on the leaf items. When a bug is created, its testing impact and priority may be known, but the technical estimate to fix isn't commonly available. This is a general statement, but makes sense most of the time.

Unless! Like us, you have transformed the bug template into a task template so that you do not create child items for a bug and instead use the bug item as if it is the resulting fix task.

Otherwise, I recommend you only track estimates based on the tasks, not the bugs. If you think about it in a team environment, the creator of the bug isn't always technical. Moreover, since rollup values are not possible in TFS right now, it's a pain to keep in sync.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on what you want to track.  If you're tracking at the bug level, you'll likely want to track the original in both places.  No matter what, you're going to have to keep the estimate to complete (ETC) updated on all tasks for appropriate reporting.